# How to pass value via `props` in export function in react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

How to use `props` in export function in react-hooks. I would like to export a function to feed `onSubmit()` in `Profile.js`.
I would like to get the `companyName` value from CompanyDetails and passed to Profile and use in onSubmit() via `props`. I am getting 'companyName' undefined error now.

```
    import CompanyDetails from "./CompanyDetails";
    
    const Profile = () =>{
    
        const onSubmit = (companyName) =>{
            const profileData = async () => {
                try {   
                  const res = await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/company', companyName);
                  if (res.data.success) {
                   
                    // push do the rest of code after save here...
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log(res.data.message);
                    
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                   console.log(e.response.data.message);
                }
              }
             //return () => { profileData() }
             profileData();
        }
        return (
            <div className="profile_wrapper">
                <div className="wrap">
                    <h1>Details:</h1>
                </div>
                <CompanyDetails 
                 onSubmit={onSubmit}
                />
            </div>
        );
    
    }
export default Profile;


export default function CompanyDetails ({onSubmit}) {
    
        const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState('');
    
        const handleChange = (e) => {
            e.persist();
            const {value} = e.target.value
            setCompanyName(value);
          }
          
      return (
        <div className="container">
            <Select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} name="company" onChange={e =>handleChange(e)} id="select">
                <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose an option</option>
                <option value="company1">Company 1</option>
                <option value="company2">Company 2</option>
            <Select>
            <Button onClick={onSubmit(companyName)} color="primary">
                Save
            </Button>
        </div> 
      );
    }
```

Comment: You're passing an object to `setCompanyName` when you should be passing a string. You're defining `companyName` as a string in your initial `useState`, so you should be setting it as a string each time you change it rather than passing an object. In additon, you have the `onSubmit` prop for `CompanyDetails` set as the return value of `onSubmit(companyName)` rather than as the actual function. Your JSX should look like `<CompanyDetails onSubmit={onSubmi)}/>`

Comment: @Rodentman87 Thank you,  I have changed the `handleChange` as ..`const {value} = e.target.value;
        setCompanyName(value);`  And then in `<CompanyDetails 
             onSubmit={onSubmit(onSubmit)}
            />` but still I am getting undefined.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from `onSubmit` in your JSX, that’s why it’s now working

Comment: @Rodentman87 In Profile.js I have made `<CompanyDetails onSubmit={onSubmit} />` Also i have updated my question with changes, could you please have a look if that is correct ..

Comment: On the Button, you want it to be `<Button onClick={() => onSubmit(companyName)} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it working. Although I had to basically rewrite everything from scratch to try and catch all the weird little bugs that would come up. But I believe the crux of the problem was making several improper function calls. You can take a look at the changes and see where I did things differently.

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chandrasekhar-fe7bt?file=/src/Profile.js) with the working code.

I had to mock making an `axios` request, but since the mock returns a promise just like an `axios` request would, you should be able to replace it with a working API on your end.

If things still aren't working, then leave a public API endpoint in the comments and I will test everything without the mocks.

Also note that sometimes I encountered an error with importing the material-ui components. But this seems to be an issue with Codesandbox and not with the components themselves.

Comment: I have made necessary changes as suggested but still this is getting undefined.

Comment: @soccerway Could you create a Codesandbox with your code for me to look at?

Comment: Updated a codesandbox link :https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-meninsky-wuob5?file=/src/Profile.js

Comment: I have added the codesandbox link for your reference please

Comment: @soccerway Sorry it took so long, it turned out to be a pretty stubborn problem. But I've got it working in the Codeandbox I linked in my answer. Let me know if it works for you and with your API

Comment: Thank you very much, now it resolved my issues. One of the problem was here `const {value} = e.target` , second one on Button `onClick={ () => onSubmit(companyName) } ` and finally on onSubmit={onSubmit} and then adding of async. Some one earlier suggest me to remove async / await

Comment: @soccerway Glad I was able to help. Wish you the best

Comment: May I ask you another question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216397/discussion-between-itsanewabstract-and-soccerway).

Answer (score 0):

at your `CompanyDetails` you need a handler for onClick like:

```
const onClickHandler = () => onSubmit(companyName)

        <Button onClick={onClickHandler} color="primary">Save</Button>
```

or pass as an arrow function:

```
<Button onClick={) => onSubmit(companyName)} color="primary">Save</Button>
```

there is also issues regarding your onSubmit function at Profile component. when you call onSubmit you return another function `return () => { profileData() }`, when you should have called `return profileData()`. though you could just mark your onSubmit function as async and avoid declaring other function inside it imho.

Comment: I have already used arrow function on button as suggested by another user. `onClick={ () => onSubmit(companyName) }` In Profile onSubmit component i have made some changes to return as suggested, commented old one and just add `profileData();`

Comment: Still companyName coming as undefined.

Comment: I believe your handle change should be `const {value} = e.target` instead of `const {value} = e.target.value`. that way you are trying to extract value from value, when it should be extracting value from target